# c# : how to easily display a Dictionary<string, int>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, controls, show

I have a dictionary that I want to show in a form.
What's the easiest way to do this ?

Preferrably I'd like to show a control where I can sort using the int-value.
I've tried a DataGridView but nothing shows up, I must be doing something wrong...

Code:

```
mDataGridView.DataSource = mWordCount; 
/*Where mWordCount is the Dictionary<string, int> but nothing shows up. (It's a forms-app, not a web-app)*/
```

Comment: ", I must be doing something wrong...)" - perhaps you could post your code to give people a clue?

Comment: Sorry, ofcourse I should post my code :)
    mDataGridView.DataSource = mWordCount;
Where mWordCount is the Dictionary<string, int>
but nothing shows up.
(It's a forms-app, not a web-app)

Comment: Try `mWordCount.ToList()` and see what happens.

Comment: @Robert - Brilliant, it works ! 
Post it as an answer and I'll give you a big-up :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `mWordCount.ToList()` and see what happens.

Explanation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx):

> The DataGridView class supports the
>   standard Windows Forms data-binding
>   model. This means the data source can
>   be of any type that implements one of
>   the following interfaces:
>
> - The `IList` interface, including    one-dimensional arrays.
> - The `IListSource` interface, such as    the `DataTable` and `DataSet`
>     classes.
> - The `IBindingList` interface, such as    the `BindingList<(Of <(T>)>)`
>     class.
> - The `IBindingListView` interface, such    as the `BindingSource` class.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you !
Can you by any chance also tell me how to display the datagrid sorted by the int-value ?

Comment: The `SortedColumn` property should allow you to do that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortedcolumn.aspx